# building Power BI report using SSAS Cube as Source

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, dax, ssas, mdx

**Requirement**: 
We are trying to build PowerBI report using SSAS Cube as a source.
Currently we already have the same report in SSRS which is using the same cube as source.
so we are upgrading to Power BI as per the user's need and the SSRS report will be decommissioned after successful implementation of this.
The SSAS cube also has some complex calculations (calculations tab of the Cube) which are used in the SSRS report.

There are  many columns which have been hidden too but are called into the SSRS Dataset.

The current SSRS report dataset has an MDX query(including some of the hidden columns) which serves as the Main query for report (Matrix type report with row groups and column groups), along with other smaller datasets which supply values to parameters

The MDX query in the SSRS report has around 6 parameters(which user can choose the values from the SSRS parameters prompts)

We are trying to find all the possible ways so that we can build the report in PowerBI

**Our findings and what we have tried so far** :
1)We have tried live connection after unhiding the columns (only those ones which are called in the MDX query) but we could not perform any transformations or calculations due to Live connection limitation.
 We thought about creating possible calculations with in the Cube level but don't know if it would actually give us the desired results correctly which would match with existing SSRS report as a comparison.

2)We tried Import mode using the same MDX query which is used in SSRS report by supplying values to the parameters(for example we passed [Report ID].[Report ID].&['a specific City name'] replaced with [Report ID].[Report ID].Children, so that we get data for all the cities instead of just 1 city) but the results are coming out incorrect.

Please if someone can provide us a valid approach on the architecture part, it would be really helpful as it will help us to get started.

Please let me know if something is not clear, so I can add more to this

Comment: TBH your approach using the MDX query in import mode sounds like the correct solution to me. You probably need to either 1) figure out and resolve the reasons why your MDX query is not producing the desired output, or 2) determine a way to parameritize your MDX query in a similar fashion to the way that the SSRS report was.